# How can I compare two arrays, removing similar items, without iterating through the whole array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, find, compare, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to compare two arrays and remove the values that are equal (if they are at the same index), without iterating through both arrays? Here is an example:

```
$array1 = @(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,23,44)
$array2 = @(1,1,3,4,5,7,6,23,45)

$array3 = $sudo_compare_function $array1 $array2
```

where `$array3` would now contain an array of indexes where `$array2` is different from `$array1` array:

```
(1,5,6,8)
```

If there isn't something like this, is there an easy way to do something similar without iterating through both arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Compare-Object` cmdlet to get an array of differing values:

```
$array1 = @(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,23,44)
$array2 = @(1,1,3,4,5,7,6,23,45)

$array3 = @(Compare-Object $array1 $array2 | select -Expand InputObject
```

For comparing just the corresponding indexes you'll have to manually make the comparison:

```
function Compare-Indexes($a1, $a2) {
  $minindex = [math]::Min($a1.Length, $a2.Length)
  $maxindex = [math]::Max($a1.Length, $a2.Length)

  for ($i = 0; $i -le $minindex; $i++) {
    if ( $a1[$i] -ne $a2[$i] ) { $i }
  }
  for ( $i = $minindex + 1; $i -le $maxindex; $i++ ) { $i }
}

$array1 = @(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,23,44)
$array2 = @(1,1,3,4,5,7,6,23,45)

$array3 = Compare-Indexes $array1 $array2
```

Comment: Won't that only give me the values that are different? I want to find the index where the difference was found in the array.

Comment: That is very specific I know of no function that does that. And iterating needs to be done. If you don't do it, the functions you call will.